# Read Ninja build file from command line

Tags: ninja

Is it possible to read a [Ninja](https://martine.github.io/ninja/) build file from STDIN, even without a `build.ninja` or other file present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `/dev/stdin` as the filename. Note that this probably won't work on Windows.

```
echo "# ninja!" | ninja -f /dev/stdin
```